# How to put one file's contents in a matrix?

Tags: file, matrix, fortran

I have a file named `test.dat` that contains 6 elements as follow:

---

> `test.dat` file's contents

---

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6

How can I put these elements in a file named `test1.dat` which contains a matrix `A(3x2)` with the following elements:

---

> Desired `test1.data` file's contents

---

> 1 2
>    3 4
>    5 6

---

In other words, how can I read each line of `test.dat` and put them as elements in matrix `A(3x2)` and save the matrix in `test1.dat` file?
So far, I tried to read each element as follow:

---

> ```
> integer function myf(unit, file, rows, columns)
>       implicit none
>       integer, intent(in) :: unit, rows, columns
>       character(len=*) :: file
>       integer, dimension (1:columns, 1:rows) ::x
>           OPEN(unit, FILE=file, STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ')
>           read(unit,*) x
>           close(unit)
>           myf= 0
> end function myf
> program test
> integer (kind=4) :: a, b, f
> INTEGER, DIMENSION(3,2) :: m
>    do a=1,3
>        do b=1,2
>              f=a*b
>              m(a,b)=myfile(99, "test.dat", f, 1)
>              write(*,*) m(a,b)
>        end do
>   end do
> end program test
> ```

---

But I just can read the first element of `test.dat` file. Now, here are my questions:

---

> 1. What is wrong with this piece of code that I can just read the first element of `test.dat` file?
> 2. How can I have control of `test.dat` file and put them in matrix `A(3x2)` as described above?

---

I appreciate it if anyone helps me in here.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm giving up trying to help you.  I can't see any evidence that you have learned from your earlier questions, the answer(s) they have brought or the comments made.  I hope someone with more patience and more time comes along to help.  Good luck.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, Sorry for my dummy questions, but I really am working on my questions and am not just waiting for the final answer. I just need some push helps. Anyways, till now, I reached to the edited code mentioned above. But I still can not read each row and put them in the matrix `A` as its elements. What is wrong with the new code?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is one example which works for reading:

You have to watch out - in Fortran, the leftmost index, in this case `i`, varies fastest, so the order of the elements is `a(1,1)`, `a(2,1)`, `a(3,1)`,
`a(1,2)` and so on.  So, if you just print the array, the output will also be
1 3 5 2 4 6 .

```
program main
  integer, dimension(3,2) :: a
  integer :: i,j

  open(20,file="test.dat")
  read (20,*) ((a(i,j),j=1,2),i=1,3)
  close (20)
  do j=1,2
     do i=1,3
        print '("A(",I1,",",I1,")=",I4)',i,j,a(i,j)
     end do
  end do

end program main
```